# No bundle URL present - React Native Application build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, apple-developer

I have a react native project that I have built. I currently test it on an emulator and my local phone. it all runs smooth. So i built it using `eas build --platform ios` and then i sent that build to the apple developer console in order to test it using Test Flight. every time it runs on test flight, it immediately crashes and I have not idea why. I can not even get access to the crash log because xcode is now working. I have no idea what is causing this.

I did look at other answers and I noticed that I do not have a

bundle URL present

for my project. I did see a solution where I add the following line of code in my `package.json` file.

```
"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='app.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
```

and then ran following command to get the app built:

```
npm run build:ios
```

when i ran the code it was giving me this error:

```
> plotis@1.0.0 build:ios
> react-native bundle --entry-file='app.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'

                    Welcome to Metro!
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated


error SHA-1 for file /Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/app.js (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/app.js) is not computed.
         Potential causes:
           1) You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks.
           2) Check `blockList` in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.
ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file /Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/app.js (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/app.js) is not computed.
         Potential causes:
           1) You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks.
           2) Check `blockList` in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.
    at DependencyGraph.getSha1 (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:191:13)
    at Transformer.transformFile (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:104:23)
    at Bundler.transformFile (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:57:30)
    at async Object.transform (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:101:12)
    at async processModule (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:18)
    at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async initialTraverseDependencies (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:114:3)
    at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:164:25)
    at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (/Users/omarjandali/dev/RGI/RGI-mobile/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:94:16)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

So I am not able to build it and run it in xcode so that I can create a production release build to publish.

Can anyone help me fix this issue that I can not figure out.

this is my app.json file:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Ryppe",
    "slug": "Ryppe",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/rgi-logo-app.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/rgi-splash-screen.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.ryppe.app",
      "buildNumber": "1"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/rgi-logo-app.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is my app.js file:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { Feather } from 'react-native-vector-icons'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'

import ContactAgentScreen from './src/screens/ContactAgentScreen';
import FavoritesScreen from './src/screens/FavoritesScreen';
import FeedScreen from './src/screens/FeedScreen';
import GalleryScreen from './src/screens/GalleryScreen';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import MainScreen from './src/screens/MainScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './src/screens/ProfileScreen';
import PropertyScreen from './src/screens/PropertyScreen';
import SellHomeScreen from './src/screens/SellHomeScreen';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import FilterScreen from './src/screens/FilterScreen'
import RecentViewScreen from './src/screens/RecentViewScreen'
import OfferInformationScreen from './src/screens/OfferInformationScreen'
import OfferScreen from './src/screens/OfferScreen'
import PaymentCalculationScreen from './src/screens/PaymentCalculationScreen'
import ThankYouScreen from './src/screens/ThankYouScreen'
import SettingsScreen from './src/screens/SettingsScreen'
import AboutUsScreen from './src/screens/AboutUsScreen'
import ResetPassword from './src/screens/ResetPassword'
import PasswordResetConfirmationScreen from './src/screens/PasswordResetConfirmationScreen'
import FullMapScreen from './src/screens/FullMapScreen'
import InvestmentScreen from './src/screens/InvestmentScreen'

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator();
const StackNav = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Home' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={MainScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="ContactAgentWithStack" component={ContactAgentScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="GallerStack" component={GalleryScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="FilterStack" component={FilterScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="OfferInformationScreen" component={OfferInformationScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="FullMapScreen" component={FullMapScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginStackScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const FeedStack = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Feed' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="FeedScreen" component={FeedScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyFeedScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginFeedScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const FavoriteStack = () => {
  return (
    //headerShown: false
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Favorite' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="FavoriteScreen" component={FavoritesScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyFavoriteScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginFavoriteScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const InvestmentStack = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Profile' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="InvestmentScreen" component={InvestmentScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyInvestmentScreen" component={PropertyScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const ProfStackile = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='Profile' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="RecentViewScreen" component={RecentViewScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="ContactAgentScreen" component={ContactAgentScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="SellHomeScreen" component={SellHomeScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="SignupScreen" component={SignupScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="OfferScreen" component={OfferScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="PaymentCalculatorScreen" component={PaymentCalculationScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="ThankYouScreen" component={ThankYouScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="AboutUsScreen" component={AboutUsScreen} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="ResetPasswordScreen" component={ResetPassword} />
      <StackNav.Screen name="PasswordResetConfirmationScreen" component={PasswordResetConfirmationScreen} />
     </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar
        animated={true}
        backgroundColor="#61dafb"
        barStyle={{color: 'black'}}/>
      <TabNav.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Home' 
          name="Home" 
          component={HomeStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"home"} color={color} size={size} />),
            tabBarShowLabel: false
          }}/> 
        {/* <TabNav.Screen key='Recommended' name="Recommended" component={RecommendedStack} /> */}
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Favorites' 
          name="Favorites" 
          component={FavoriteStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"heart"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Feed' 
          name="Feed" 
          component={FeedStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"menu"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Propertyies' 
          name="Properties" 
          component={InvestmentStack} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"trending-up"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
        {/* <TabNav.Screen key='Messages' name="Messages" component={MessagesStack} />  */}
        <TabNav.Screen 
          key='Profile' 
          name="Profile" 
          component={ProfStackile} 
          options={{
            tabBarShowLabel: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"user"} color={color} size={size} />)
          }}/>
      </TabNav.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

export default App;
```

this is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "plotis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='app.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.11",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-email": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.30.2",
    "react-native-tag-select": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```